# Elasticsearch index limit?

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm working with Symfony 4, [FosElasticaBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle) and Kibana, and I have approximatly 600K items to index in ElasticSearch.

I'm using the command `fos:elastica:populate`, and when I run this I have something like :

```
 Resetting myindex
 0/546097 [>---------------------------]   0%
```

So, `546097` is the exact number of items I need to index, but after the indexation, when I try to get all items in ElasticSearch with curl like :

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query" : {
       "match_all" : {}
     }
}'
```

**I have `count=420,603`**

When I try to check the index with Kibana, I can see the same count `420,603`.

I did the indexation several times (reset + index), and it's always the same count of `420603`....

So my question is : What is this limit ? Why the indexation stop to 420603 items exactly ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you check the logs to see if there were errors during indexing?

Comment: The logs of what ?

Comment: Is it possible to post a sample document of what you were trying to index?